# Jquery carousel autoscroll

Tags: jquery, carousel

Good Day,

I have a problem with my jquery carousel, I did it everything works fine but only when I click on arrow, but I dont know how can I work autoscroll. This is my code. Can you help me? Thank you for replies.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //move he last list item before the first item. The purpose of this is if the user clicks to slide left he will be able to see the last item.
        $('#carousel_ulP li:first').before($('#carousel_ulP li:last')); 


        //when user clicks the image for sliding right        
        $('#right_scrollP img').click(function(){

            //get the width of the items ( i like making the jquery part dynamic, so if you change the width in the css you won't have o change it here too ) '
            var item_width = $('#carousel_ulP li').outerWidth() + 10;

            //calculae the new left indent of the unordered list
            var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ulP').css('left')) - item_width;

            //make the sliding effect using jquery's anumate function '
            $('#carousel_ulP:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    
                auto: 2,
                //get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made) '
                $('#carousel_ulP li:last').after($('#carousel_ulP li:first')); 

                //and get the left indent to the default -210px
                $('#carousel_ulP').css({'left' : '-210px'});
            }); 
        });

        //when user clicks the image for sliding left
        $('#left_scrollP img').click(function(){

            var item_width = $('#carousel_ulP li').outerWidth() + 10;

            /* same as for sliding right except that it's current left indent + the item width (for the sliding right it's - item_width) */
            var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ulP').css('left')) + item_width;

            $('#carousel_ulP:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    

            /* when sliding to left we are moving the last item before the first list item */            
            $('#carousel_ulP li:first').before($('#carousel_ulP li:last')); 

            /* and again, when we make that change we are setting the left indent of our unordered list to the default -210px */
            $('#carousel_ulP').css({'left' : '-210px'});
            });


        });
  });
```

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle?

Comment: You can see it http://tosa.betaverzia.sk/ on bottom site.